# Tkinter Entry variable rror

Tags: python, tkinter

I have follow many tutorials and i have written this lines of code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def queryInsert(nameEntry):
    print(nameEntry)
def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Personal Network - Add Person")
    root.geometry('400x270')
    root.resizable(False, False)

    Label(root, text='Name').place(x=20,y=20)
    Label(root, text='Surname').place(x=20, y=50)
    Label(root, text='Birthday').place(x=20, y=75)
    Label(root, text='Phone').place(x=20, y=100)
    Label(root, text='Adress').place(x=20, y=125)
    Label(root, text='City').place(x=20, y=150)

    namePerson = StringVar()
    nameEntry = ttk.Entry(root, textvariable=namePerson).place(x=60, y=20)
    Button(root, text="Initialize DB", command=queryInsert(nameEntry.get()), width=15).place(x=100, y=50)


    root.mainloop()
```

But i have this kind of error:

```
Button(root, text="Initialize DB", command=queryInsert(nameEntry.get()), width=15).place(x=100, y=50)
```

I have search many blog post and all do the same thing. I don't understand why. I am trying to display only the value of input field.

Comment: What is the error?  Note that `nameEntry` is None because it is the result of `place(...)`. Also `command=queryInsert(...)` will execute `queryInsert(...)` *immediately*, not when the button is clicked.

Comment: I understand the first part, Infact now i split the line. But i use other button and the function will part on click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues in your code:

- `nameEntry` is `None` because it is the result of `.place(...)`, so calling `nameEntry.get()` will raise exception. You can use `namePerson.get()` instead.
- `command=queryInsert(...)` will execute `queryInsert(...)` *immediately*, you need to use `lambda` instead.

Below is the modified code:

```py
...
namePerson = StringVar()
ttk.Entry(root, textvariable=namePerson).place(x=60, y=20)
Button(root, text="Initialize DB", command=lambda: queryInsert(namePerson.get()), width=15).place(x=100, y=50)
...
```